# Save CPLEX preprocessing/aggregation

Tags: c++, optimization, cplex

I'm using the C++ CPLEX API to model MILP problems. CPLEX "simplifies" my models before solving them (i.e., via the aggregator, MILP presolve, substitutions, etc.).  When I use the `exportModel` method of the `IloCplex` class it only considers the original model.

Is it possible to save the reduced model?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this using the C++ API (you don't have access to the presolve model via the object oriented Concert layers).  You can do it programmatically with the [C Callable Library](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/homepageCrefman.html) or the [Python API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html?pos=2).  Alternatively, you can do it manually with the [interactive](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/homepages/interactiveoptimizercommands.html), like so:

```
CPLEX> read model.sav
CPLEX> write model.lp
CPLEX> write presolved.pre
CPLEX> read presolved.pre
CPLEX> write presolved.lp
```

This example assumes that you've exported your original model in [SAV format](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/SAV.html).  After following those steps, you'd end up with `presolved.lp` (the presolved model in [LP format](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP.html)).  If you wanted to do it programmatically (using one of the API's above), you'd follow the same steps.